# Decrypt string via OpenSSL

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

My goal is to decrypt a base64 encoded string.

Running the command fully works:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-128-cbc -iv '{iv}' -K {hex_key} <<< {hex_enc_password}
```

I'd like to do the exact same via the C api. I know there're many similar questions on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work for me, so I kindly ask you **not** to flag this as duplicate.

Info:

- **hex_enc_password** is base64 encoded
- **hex_key** is a string as byte-string (via hexlify()) (example: 0x1a,0xc4 -> "1ac4")

My current Code:

```
char* key = "lbzA54tAAg3E/jPxiJc34e==";
unsigned char *hex_key = hexlify(key);

char encrypted[] = {0x3d,0xd2,0x02,0xc3,0xae,0x1e,0xf5,0x7e,0x33,0xc3,0x1d,0x7b,0x1e,0x48,0x73,0x84};
size_t output_length;
unsigned char *hex_enc_password = base64_encode(encrypted, sizeof(encrypted), &output_length);

decrypt(hex_enc_password, strlen(hex_enc_password),hex_key, iv);

char* decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv ) {
    int outLen1 = 0; int outLen2 = 0;
    unsigned char *outdata = malloc(ciphertext_len+1);
    bzero(outdata, ciphertext_len+1);
    //setup decryption
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit(ctx,EVP_aes_128_cbc(),key,iv);                     //returns 1
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,outdata,&outLen1,ciphertext,ciphertext_len); //returns 1
    EVP_DecryptFinal(ctx,outdata + outLen1,&outLen2);                  //returns 0

    return outdata;
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If `ciphertext` is base-64 encoded, you'd have to decode that first. (Easy to do with OpenSSL; there's a BIO filter for it.) Same applies if it's base-16 encoded like some of your other variables suggest.

Comment: @Shawn I encoded it on purpose, since it works great via the terminal command

Comment: There's also a complete lack of any error checking or handling. You should do that; how else are you supposed to know when something doesn't work?

Comment: @JohnSmith Please do not include tags in the title redundantly. After all, we specifically have tags for that.

Comment: @Shawn well those 4 Function calls only return 1 on success and 0 on failure, no other error code. Besides that I removed most error checking, so the code is more readable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph having C API in the title is important, otherwise it could mean that the terminal command is also possible, but the goal is pure c code

Comment: @JohnSmith The tags clearly state that this question is regarding C, mentioning it again in the title is redundant. Nobody will be confused.

Comment: Your argument data is wrong. `strlen(hex_enc_password)` is *certainly* wrong for the input size of ciphertext. An AES encryption can (and often does) have embedded null octets. Or worse, it doesn't and your "size" calculation runs into abyss past viable memory, searching for a terminator until it finally finds one (if it finds one). Either way, that size argument is flat-out wrong. I cannot tell you whether, or how badly, the other arguments are setup because you have no reproducible case here, and this isn't 20 questions.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have the ciphertext as exact bytes, I then encode it into base64, which returns a string, therefore I thought it would make sense here. (See my edited code)

Comment: `EVP_DecryptXXXX` does not expect, nor will it properly deal with, a base64-encoded *anything*. Not the key, not the IV, and not the cipher text.

Comment: @WhozCraig good guess, but I base64-decoded both ciphertext and key and still not the correct result

Comment: It's not a guess. at least one of your arguments isn't correct, or align to what the EVP api is expecting. Arguments are really the *only* thing different from your code vs. every other basic EVP encrypt/decrypt code block you'll ever see. Your Final call is failing because either the key, the IV and/or the data, doesn't line up to determine the padding to discard from the ciphertext (which is always in the last frame, and could be as large as a full aes block size). The other two APIs will take almost anything, and don't care whether its right or wrong, but Final *does*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yay, I got it to work. I basically did everything step for step like the openssl binary does (source code, github), and yes everything needs to be decoded from base64. I'm still not sure what I did different, since I also tested without base64 encoding before, but somehow it works now.

Comment: Whenever I have to do something like this, I always (a) write the encryption side, (b) write the decryption side, then test to make sure it works. Then, wedge the encode-to and decode-from steps in between, then test to make sure it *still* works. if that breaks things, you know where things went off the rails; encode/decode. Anyway, glad you go a handle on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.
As described in the comments above, nothing should be encoded in base64. Calling the command line binary with the `-base64` simply makes openssl decode it before continuing. Same goes for hexlifying, just skip that.

Everything besides that should be the same as above.